# C# error casting from double to int32

Tags: c#

```
using NUF = NUnit.Framework;
[NUF.Test]public void DifferentCastingTest() {
     NUF.Assert.That((int)0.499999D, NUF.Is.EqualTo(0)); 
     NUF.Assert.That((int)0.500000D, NUF.Is.EqualTo(0)); // !!! row 1
     NUF.Assert.That((int)1.499999D, NUF.Is.EqualTo(1)); 
     NUF.Assert.That((int)1.500000D, NUF.Is.EqualTo(1)); // !!! row 2

     NUF.Assert.That(System.Convert.ToInt32(0.499999D), NUF.Is.EqualTo(0)); 
     NUF.Assert.That(System.Convert.ToInt32(0.500000D), NUF.Is.EqualTo(0)); // !!! 
     NUF.Assert.That(System.Convert.ToInt32(1.499999D), NUF.Is.EqualTo(1)); 
     NUF.Assert.That(System.Convert.ToInt32(1.500000D), NUF.Is.EqualTo(2)); //!!! row 3
  }
```

The same double value (1.5D) is converted in different way by casting and Convert.ToInt32 (see row 2 and 3), and two double with same mantissa (0.5 and 1.5) is rounded in different mode (see row 1 and 2).
Is it a bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope, it's documented behaviour. [`Convert.ToInt32(double)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ffdk7eyz.aspx) rounds a number up or down, with half-way points rounding to even:

> **Return Value**
>
> `value`, rounded to the nearest 32-bit signed integer. If `value` is halfway between two 
>   whole numbers, the even number is returned; that is, 4.5 is converted to 4, and 5.5 is 
>   converted to 6.

Casting always rounds towards zero (so 1.8 rounds to one, for example) - from section 6.2.1 of the C# 3 spec:

> ...
>
> Otherwise, the source operand is
>   rounded towards zero to the nearest
>   integral value. If this integral value
>   is within the range of the destination
>   type then this value is the result of
>   the conversion.

Note that this isn't just about bankers' rounding: it's about rounding in general: there's a difference between `(int)0.9` and `Convert.ToInt32(0.9)`.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not a bug.  [.Net uses banker's rounding by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s2d3xkk.aspx).
If it's not desirable behavior, you can specify the rounding method.

Answer (score 2):

Casting always truncates the number rather than rounding it.

For example, `int new = (int)1.999999D;` would give you an int named new with the value `1`.

`Convert.ToInt32` says it returns this:

> value, rounded to the nearest 32-bit
>   signed integer. If value is halfway
>   between two whole numbers, the even
>   number is returned; that is, 4.5 is
>   converted to 4, and 5.5 is converted
>   to 6.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly according to both the language spec and the MSDN documentation.

Casting to an integer by design returns the integer part of a floating point number, and the return value of Convert.ToInt32 is rounded to the nearest 32-bit signed integer. If value is halfway between two whole numbers, the even number is returned; that is, 4.5 is converted to 4, and 5.5 is converted to 6.